# Mac: auto connect to IOBluetoothDevice

Tags: macos, bluetooth

I select an IOBluetoothDevice with IOBluetoothDeviceSelector. After that, I do some things with the device; doesn't matter.

Is it possible to save the IOBluetoothDevice and auto connect when the device is close enough? (after restart of the app too)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you find the solution to this question? i have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

`IOBluetoothDevice` has the following methods which will be useful to you:

`- [IOBluetoothDevice addressString]` which will provide you with the address of the device as a string you can easily store in your apps defaults.

`+ [IOBluetoothDevice deviceWithAddressString:(NSString*) address]` will allow you to construct an `IOBluetoothDevice*` with that address string after the app has restarted.

`- [IOBluetoothDevice openConnection]` or `- [IOBluetoothDevice openConnection:(id)delegate]` which will allow you to open a connection to the device you created, either synchronously or asynchronously.